# 10k Tools flag tab shows a post I already flagged

Tags: bug, flagging, 10k-tools

I recently gained access to the "10k tools". Today, I flagged an answer as "not an answer" through the Low Quality review queue. When I switched to the "Tools" tab, I saw that same answer yet again:

[image]

complete with my own flag. Other posts, which I flagged through the 10k tools, are hidden from view (as one should generally only flag a post once).